# Remove specific error message from Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-confirmable

In Devise, when confirmation instructions are resent and the email doesn't exist in the database, we get the error

> Email not found

However, due to security, I want to remove this specific error.

I'm using custom controllers but the confirmation#create method is just invoking `super`.
Under that, I've removed the `email` field from the errors using

```
resource.errors.delete('email')
```

Printing out the errors (in the controller) after the fact shows nothing for `email`. However, when the request goes through and I print the `resource.errors` object in the shared errors partial, the error is still there.

Is there any way to remove this error completely? I'm assuming some other action is happening after the `#create` method that's injecting the error again.

Full method

```
def create
  super
  resource.errors.delete('email')
end
```

Confirmation of deletion:

[image]

Confirmation that error persists after redirect:

[image]

Comment: Wait. Hold up. Have you heard about `paranoid` mode in Devise? In your application configuration, there should be a file with `Devise.setup do |config| ...` and a commented-out line: `# config.paranoid = true`. Does uncommenting that solve your problem, rather than trying to custom-build your own solution?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Using-paranoid-mode,-avoid-user-enumeration-on-registerable